# App Automacao Residencial

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um app de automação residencial, nele eu tenho a tela principal
que ao selecionar a categoria desejada ele abre uma segunda tela com os comandos (exemplo categoria luzes, ele abre os comando Luz1, Luz2, etc), ao clicar no ImageButton da luz1 ele altera o ícone (luzOff para luzOn), ao voltar para a tela principal e entrar novamente na categoria de luzes eu perco o meu ultimo estado do ImageButton. Exemplo eu abri a categoria luz e deixei a Luz1 acesa (ImageButton vai alterar o ícone para luzOn), mais quando eu saio para a tela principal e volto para a tela de luzes ele abre com o ícone luzOff mesmo eu deixando a luz acessa. Como faco para o ícone sempre manter seu ultimo estado deixado, toda vez que abro a tela ? (Desculpe se não fui claro e porque e meio difícil explicar o que eu quero).

```
public class Home extends Activity{ 

        private ImageButton btnLuz1;
        private ImageButton btnLuz2;
        Button btnVoltar;
        private Set<String> botoesOn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);

            btnVoltar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
            btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent voltaTela = new Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Home.this.startActivity(voltaTela);
                    Home.this.finish();

                }
            });

            btnLuz1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLuz1);
            btnLuz2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLuz2);

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            botoesOn = prefs.getStringSet("botoes", null);

            if(botoesOn == null){
                botoesOn = new HashSet<String>();
            }
            else{
                if(botoesOn.contains("botao1")){
                    btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
                }
                if(botoesOn.contains("botao2")){
                    btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
                }
            }
        }

        public void btnLuz1Click(View v){
            if(botoesOn.contains("botao1")){
                botoesOn.remove("botao1");
                btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzoff);
            }
            else{
                botoesOn.add("botao1");
                btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
            }
        }

        public void btnLuz2Click(View v){
            if(botoesOn.contains("botao2")){
                botoesOn.remove("botao2");
                btnLuz2.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzoff);
            }
            else{
                botoesOn.add("botao2");
                btnLuz2.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
            }
        }

        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            prefs.edit().putStringSet("botoes", botoesOn).apply();
        }

    }
```

e o xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLuz1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnLuzes"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:onClick="bt1Click"
    android:src="@drawable/luzoff" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLuz2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnLuz1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:onClick="bt2Click"
    android:src="@drawable/luzoff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnVoltar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnLuzes"
    android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
    android:text="Voltar" />
```

Log do Erro:

```
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bt1Click [class android.view.View]
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
05-07 11:50:45.466: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: É mais um erro devido à tradução do nome dos métodos do meu teste para os nomes que você utiliza na pergunta. No *XML* nos atributos `android:onClick` substitua `bt1Click` por `btnLuz1Click` e `bt2Click` por `btnLuz2Click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) para guardar o estados dos botões.

Comece por declarar um HashSet que irá guardar os botões que estão ON:

```
private Set<String> botoesOn;
```

Em cada um dos métodos `onClick()` dos botões

```
if(botoesOn.contais("botao1"){
    botoesOn.remove("botao1");
    //Passar o botão para OFF
}
else{
    botoesOn.add("botao1");
    //Passar o botão para ON
}
```

Substitua em cada um dos métodos `"botao1"` por `"botao2"`,`"botao3"`, etc.

No método `onPause()` guarde o HashSet na *SharedPreference*:

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putStringSet("botoes", botoesON).apply();
}
```

No método `onCreate()` obtenha o *HashSet* e actualize os botões de acordo com o seu estado anterior:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
botoesOn = prefs.getStringSet("botoes", null);

if(botoesOn == null){
    botoesOn = new HashSet<String>();
}
else{
    if(botoesOn.contains("botao1")){
        // colocar botao1 ON
    }
    if(botoesOn.contains("botao2")){
        // colocar botao2 ON
    }
    if(botoesOn.contains("botao3")){
        // colocar botao3 ON
    }
    ... //Repetir para todos os botões
    ...
}
```

Tudo junto é assim:

```
public class TesteActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton btnLuz1;
    private ImageButton btnLuz2;
    private Set<String> botoesOn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.teste);

        btnLuz1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLuz1);
        btnLuz2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLuz2);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        botoesOn = prefs.getStringSet("botoes", null);

        if(botoesOn == null){
            botoesOn = new HashSet<String>();
        }
        else{
            if(botoesOn.contains("botao1")){
                btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
            }
            if(botoesOn.contains("botao2")){
                btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
            }
        }
    }

    public void btnLuz1Click(View v){
        if(botoesOn.contains("botao1")){
            botoesOn.remove("botao1");
            btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzoff);
        }
        else{
            botoesOn.add("botao1");
            btnLuz1.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
        }
    }

    public void btnLuz2Click(View v){
        if(botoesOn.contains("botao2")){
            botoesOn.remove("botao2");
            btnLuz2.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzoff);
        }
        else{
            botoesOn.add("botao2");
            btnLuz2.setImageResource(R.drawable.luzon);
        }
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit().putStringSet("botoes", botoesOn).apply();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#F3F3F3">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLuz1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/luzoff" 
        android:onClick="btnLuz1Click"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLuz2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/luzoff" 
        android:onClick="btnLuz2Click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Por favor não usem os comentários para discussões extensas. A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23557/discussion-on-answer-by-ramaral-app-automacao-residencial).

Answer (score 1):

Existem diferentes maneiras de se fazer isso:

- **Salvar estado dos botões no banco (O que recomendo).**
- Receber as modificações feitas na sua activity de comandos, utilizando o método *[onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)*, e depois, ao voltar a activity de comandos, voce passa o ultimo estado armazenado. Utilizando [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (dados *extra*)

Comment: Certo, mais eu tinha feito uma vez sem banco só que eu perdi o código, no momento não penso em usar um banco acho desnecessário para meu app. Você conhece outra forma de fazer isso tipo utilizando uma flag para verificar o ImageButton toda vez que eu abro o activity Luzes, ou algum outro meio ? Se não, muito obg pelo resposta.

Comment: @ItalloFreire Se o seu sistema é de automação residencial, você PRECISA de um banco. Como o sistema vai se comportar quando faltar a energia, ou o mesmo for desligado? As luzes vão continuar ligadas ou vão voltar para a definição default do teu programa? Dados importantes, principalmente dados que fazem alguma diferença no mundo real, precisam ser guardados em um banco de dados confiável.

Comment: E pq a gente desenvolveu uma placa de circuito(central) especialmente para isso então quando a energia e cortada e retorna a central retorna o ultimo estado que foi deixada. Quero fazer sem banco primeiro para realizar alguns teste. Vou usar o aparelho (tablet ou celular) para ler o estado da central, para verificar se esta acesa, apagado, tvOn, etc.. Por isso acho desnecessário o banco eu tbm sou leigo na programação android e estou com algumas dificuldades. Mesmo assim obg pela dica.

Comment: @ItalloFreire, é muito recomendavel um banco de dados, voce precisar armazenar várias informacoes sobre o usuario, como preferencia, horarios, dimensões, etc. Armazenar tudo isso em Shared Preferences não é muito eficiente...

Comment: @Renaro Santos - Certo entendo, mais eu teria que aprender tudo sobre banco no android, pois sou leigo no assunto, teria que fazer curso e não estou com tempo disponível para isso no momento. Teria alguma dica como fazer isso ? estou ficando sem tempo tbm preciso terminar esse projeto logo.